# MVC Web Grid submit

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webgrid

I am trying to use a WebGrid to display some data, this is fine but I also want to add a column with a submit button that passes back an id from the model. here is my grid code

```
   @{var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);}
   <div>
        <h2>Multi User Login</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("CompanyName"),
            grid.Column("Address"),
            grid.Column(format: @<input type="submit" name="@item.idAddress" value = "select" />)))


        }

</div>
```

I have tried a number of ways to return the idAddress to the controller post method without any luck. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using an ActionLink instead, if the only thing you want is the ID?

```
@{var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);}
<div>
   <h2>Multi User Login</h2>
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
      @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
         grid.Column("CompanyName"),
         grid.Column("Address"),
         grid.Column(format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Click me", "MyAction", new { Id = item.idAddress}))
      ))
   }
</div>
```

Or is it important that you do a POST?

Comment: Hi Mike thanks for the response I ended up using an action link and redirecting to another controller action, I was hoping I could have done this with a post though.

Comment: Use some jQuery magic to do the post if that is important to you.
Mark the question as answered as well, if you find your issue resolved.